# Cannot open TexStudio on Mac after force quit when freezed because of autosaving fail

Tags: texstudio, mac

I force quit TexStudio because it was not responded after attempt auto saving new file fail. After that, I cannot open TexStudio any more. The program starts running in Activity Monitor, but stops after a few seconds.

The environment is:

- TeXstudio: 2.12.14
- Qt: 7.7.3
- OS: Mac 10.13.6
- TeX distribution: texlive

A few things I tried but did not help:

- Installing new version in Applications folder.
- Delete texstudio.ini
  file.
- Delete texstudio settings folder.

How can I open TexStudio again?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out restarting the computer fixed the problem. It took me awhile to tried this because my computer was running some experiments at the time.

It seems the bug is related to Qt, because all other related programs also failed to work.